# Less File Watcher creates empty files in PhpStorm

Tags: less, phpstorm, file-watcher, clean-css

I have setup the file watcher in PhpStorm from it's default settings.
After modifying the filenames and adding `--source-map` argument, the generated CSS file is empty.

Arguments: 
`--no-color` 
`--clean-css` 
`--source--map=$FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css.map' 
'$FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.min.css`

And when I run the command directly in Mac Terminal, the file is generated well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uncheck `Create output file from stdout` in `Advanced Options` of your File Watcher